# How to display error message conditionally based on ajax response jquery validation?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I want to apply error class and validation error message as per jquery validation plugin conditionally based on ajax response on the `blur` event of element. i get response either `1` or `0` from ajax. and if i get `0` in 'data' i have shown validation message as bellow,

```
  $("#txtFinalGSTNo").rules("add", {
                    messages: "Invalid Provisional GST Number"
                });
```

but message is not being display. while 'bootbox.alert("Invalid Provisional GST Number");' alert message is being displayed. as rules is not being apply for message.

i have created jquery as bellow, and add error message to display.

```
$(".gstFild").blur(function () {

    var txtPanNo = $("#txtCompanyPanNo").val();
    var txtGstNo = "";

    if ($("#ddlCountry").val() == 180 && $("#CheckboxGST").prop("checked") == true) {
        if ($("#hiddenProType").val() == "1") {
            txtGstNo = $("#txtProvisionalGSTNo").val();
        }
        else if ($("#hiddenProType").val() == "2") {
            txtGstNo = $("#txtFinalGSTNo").val();
        }

    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("CheckGSTValidate", "StaticPage")",
        data: { SelectedStateValue: $("#ddlState").val(), txtPanNo: txtPanNo, txtGstNo: txtGstNo },
        success: function (data) {

            if (data == 0) {
                if ($("#hiddenProType").val() == "1") {

                    $("#txtFinalGSTNo").rules("add", {
                        messages: "Invalid Provisional GST Number"
                    });

                    //bootbox.alert("Invalid Provisional GST Number");

                }
                else if ($("#hiddenProType").val() == "2") {


                    $("#txtFinalGSTNo").rules("add", {
                        messages: "Invalid Final GST Number"
                    });

                    //bootbox.alert("Invalid Final GST Number");

                }
            }
            else {

                if ($("#hiddenProType").val() == "1") {
                    $("#txtProvisionalGSTNo").rules("remove", "messages");
                }
                else if ($("#hiddenProType").val() == "2") {
                    $("#txtFinalGSTNo").rules("remove", "messages");
                }



            }
        }
    });

});
```

html code block as bellow,

```
   <div class="three-column-form">
                                <div class="business-details-row">
                                    <div class="left-column">
                                        <div class="chkbox-wrap">
                                            <input id="CheckboxGST" type="checkbox" name="IsGstApplicabler" disabled="disabled">
                                            <label class="indeschead" for="CheckboxGST">GST APPLICABLE</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="left-column margin">
                                        @if (ViewBag.GstProStatus == 1)
                                        {
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <label><span>*</span>Provisional GST no.</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="gstFild" id="txtProvisionalGSTNo" disabled="disabled" name="ProvisionalGSTNo" data-validation="required">
                                            </div>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <label><span>*</span>Final GST no.</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="gstFild" id="txtFinalGSTNo" disabled="disabled" name="FinalGSTNo" data-validation="required">
                                            </div>
                                        }

                                    </div>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenProvisopnalTp" id="hiddenProType" value="@ViewBag.GstProStatus" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Can you show what `data` has in it?

Comment: So what problem are you having? What is not working?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay response from ajax as `data` is either `1` or `0`

Comment: @StephenMuecke validation message is not being display while alert message is displaying.

Comment: Why are you not using the jquery client side validation with `ValidationMessageFor()` that is built in to the frame work?

Comment: Just like in your previous questions about the jQuery Validate plugin, you're not reading and/or following [the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).

Answer (score 0):

> *"but message is not being display"*

You're not using [the `.rules()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) properly because the message is not assigned to any rule.

```
$("#txtFinalGSTNo").rules("add", {
    messages: "Invalid Provisional GST Number"  // <- which rule??
});
```

In order to dynamically change the message, you need to specify the applicable rule within the `messages` object.

```
$("#txtFinalGSTNo").rules("add", {
    messages: {
        required: "custom required message here"
    }
});
```

You can dynamically change this message by calling this method above again but with a new message.

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/a4zbp7dh/](https://jsfiddle.net/a4zbp7dh/)**

Answer (score -2):

The error messages are showing based on the response from `url`, below added an additional span id's `txtProvisionalGSTNo_msg` and `txtFinalGSTNo_msg` to display messages.

**jquery**

```
$(".gstFild").blur(function () {

    var txtPanNo = $("#txtCompanyPanNo").val();
    var txtGstNo = "";

    if ($("#ddlCountry").val() == 180 && $("#CheckboxGST").prop("checked") == true) {
        if ($("#hiddenProType").val() == "1") {
            txtGstNo = $("#txtProvisionalGSTNo").val();
        }
        else if ($("#hiddenProType").val() == "2") {
            txtGstNo = $("#txtFinalGSTNo").val();
        }

    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("CheckGSTValidate", "StaticPage")",
        data: { SelectedStateValue: $("#ddlState").val(), txtPanNo: txtPanNo, txtGstNo: txtGstNo },
        success: function (data) {

            $("#txtProvisionalGSTNo_msg").html("");
            $("#txtFinalGSTNo_msg").html("");

            if (data == 0) {
                if ($("#hiddenProType").val() == "1") {

                    $("#txtProvisionalGSTNo_msg").html("Invalid Provisional GST Number");

                    //bootbox.alert("Invalid Provisional GST Number");

                }
                else if ($("#hiddenProType").val() == "2") {


                    $("#txtFinalGSTNo_msg").html("Invalid Final GST Number");

                    //bootbox.alert("Invalid Final GST Number");

                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**html block**

```
<div class="three-column-form">
<div class="business-details-row">
    <div class="left-column">
        <div class="chkbox-wrap">
            <input id="CheckboxGST" type="checkbox" name="IsGstApplicabler" disabled="disabled">
            <label class="indeschead" for="CheckboxGST">GST APPLICABLE</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left-column margin">
        @if (ViewBag.GstProStatus == 1)
        {
            <div class="form-row">
                <label><span>*</span>Provisional GST no.</label>
                <input type="text" class="gstFild" id="txtProvisionalGSTNo" disabled="disabled" name="ProvisionalGSTNo" data-validation="required">
                <span id="txtProvisionalGSTNo_msg"></span>
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="form-row">
                <label><span>*</span>Final GST no.</label>
                <input type="text" class="gstFild" id="txtFinalGSTNo" disabled="disabled" name="FinalGSTNo" data-validation="required">
                <span id="txtFinalGSTNo_msg"></span>
            </div>
        }

    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenProvisopnalTp" id="hiddenProType" value="@ViewBag.GstProStatus" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your point is quite related. but i want to add error class and error message as per jquery validation plugin.

Comment: You never mentioned what rules you wanted to add. There are some set of standard validation methods. check https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/